# To Zoom in or Zoom out in a chrome browser using UFT/QTP

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript, zooming, hp-uft

without creating new instance of chrome browser how to change the zoom level on the same page of google chrome which is already under test execution using UFT/QTP

Answer (score 0):

shortcuts are the way:

```
Ctrl and 0 (zero) - reset to 100%
Ctrl and +        - zoom in
Ctrl and -        - zoom out
```

Comment: Are these shortcuts available using UFT/QTP?

Comment: There are multiple ways to send Shortcuts in UFT.



   1. The . Type method of WebObjects
   2. Mercury.DeviceReplay Object SendKeys method
   3. WshShell.SendKeys method

The ctrl button has different representations, depending on the method you use: micCtrl or {CTRL}. For further details about the methods please look up their APIs